# Can I make column names all lower case upon import using pandas read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I am parsing a payload and want to import only those columns that I am including in my model. I can easily do this in pandas using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(values), delimiter=',', usecols=LIST_COLS)
```

However, my fear is that sometimes the column names (often camel case) will not match the column names in the model. Thus, prior to training my model, I converted all column names to lower case. Now, when I import my data I want to import the column names as lower to ensure everything will match up when all portions of the payload are concatenated and a prediction needs to be generated.

I am assuming this is possible but I do not know how to do this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()`

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) of `pandas.read_csv`

> **usecols** : list-like or callable, optional

Modify your code as below using callable `lambda` function:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(values), delimiter=',', usecols=lambda x: x.lower() in LIST_COLS)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://symbiosisacademy.org/tutorial-index/pandas-read_csv_select-skip-rows-columns/).

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(values), delimiter=',', usecols=lambda col: col.lower() in LIST_COLS)
```

Then, I can convert them to lower using:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower() # from Alexander's answer
```